# In mixed string, make the chars key of an array and numbers it's values in PHP

Tags: php

For a given string ex. P52I2211M599, return  `$arr = ['P' => 52, 'I' => 2211, 'M' => 599];`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There's nothing wrong with asking for some help with your homework/assignment, but you are expected to make an effort of your own. We're not here to write the whole code for you. See [how to ask a homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: yeah, you're right. Sorry, I should've spent more time solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First match the pattern of the string using a regular expression, then loop all matches and set the key and value in the array.

```
<?php

$array = [];
$string = "P52I2211M599";
preg_match_all("/[A-Z]\d+/", $string, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $value) {
    $array[substr($value, 0, 1)] = substr($value, 1);
}
```

Comment: I like how you only provided a solution for the OP's exact example rather than a full solution to extended prefixes, ie: `PZ52` where the output would be `PZ => 52`. He might **try it himself** this time if he in the likely situation has to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I come up with this solution after some exploring:

```
function extractNumbers($string) {

    $delimiter = range("A", "Z");
    $chars  = implode($delimiter);
    $arrValues = preg_split("/[$chars]+/", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    return array_combine(array_filter(array_map(function($value){
        if(!is_numeric($value)){
            return $value;
        }
    }, str_split($string))), $arrValues);
}

var_dump(extractNumbers('P52I2211M599'));
```

Comment: It works up until the string contains multiple prefixes prior to the number. IE `PZ52`. You should count how many are not numeric use that as the offset.

Comment: yeah you are right, I don't need that for now, but it will a good exercise, not sure how to get that PZ => 52

Comment: I played with the other answer & [got it working](https://3v4l.org/kvJ0J).

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With preg_match_all the key and the values can be get separately. The desired array can be generated directly with array_combine.

```
$string = "P52I2211M599";
preg_match_all("/([A-Z]+)(\d+)/", $string, $matches);
$array = array_combine($matches[1],$matches[2]);
```

var_export($array):

```
array (
  'P' => "52",
  'I' => "2211",
  'M' => "599",
)
```